# FullCalendar Resources Grouping does not work with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I was trying to implement the exact same example [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-resourceGroupField-demo)

but in React:

```
<FullCalendar
            plugins={[
              interactionPlugin,
              timelinePlugin,
              resourceTimelinePlugin,
            ]}
            header={{
              left: 'today prev,next',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek',
            }}
            aspectRatio={1.6}
            defaultView="resourceTimelineDay"
            resourceGroupField="building"
            schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source"
            resources={[
              { id: 'a', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium A' },
              { id: 'b', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium B' },
              { id: 'c', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium C' },
              { id: 'd', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium D' },
              { id: 'e', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium E' },
              { id: 'f', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium F' },
              { id: 'g', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium G' },
              { id: 'h', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium H' },
              { id: 'i', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium I' },
              { id: 'j', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium J' },
              { id: 'k', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium K' },
              { id: 'l', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium L' },
              { id: 'm', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium M' },
              { id: 'n', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium N' },
              { id: 'o', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium O' },
              { id: 'p', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium P' },
              { id: 'q', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium Q' },
              { id: 'r', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium R' },
              { id: 's', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium S' },
              { id: 't', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium T' },
              { id: 'u', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium U' },
              { id: 'v', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium V' },
              { id: 'w', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium W' },
              { id: 'x', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium X' },
              { id: 'y', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium Y' },
              { id: 'z', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium Z' },
            ]}
          />
```

I imported the following in the styles.scss file:

```
@import "~@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
@import "~@fullcalendar/timeline/main.css";
@import "~@fullcalendar/resource-timeline/main.css";
```

But I got the following result:

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing, but the group fields are not showing.

Comment: Unless you've scrolled across, it appears the entire resources block is missing, not just the groups. And something is screwy with your CSS judging by the line spacing in the grid - have you been customising the fullCalendar CSS, or maybe got some other CSS in the page which might conflict with it?

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in your Console? And/or did any of the JS or CSS files fail to load (you can check the Network tool to know that)?

Comment: P.S. per that example from the fullCalendar website, you should only need to load the resourceTimeline plugin to make it work. So to create a minimal example for yourself, and rule out any strange interference, please remove the interaction and timeline plugins and re-test. i.e. I mean change `plugins={[
              interactionPlugin,
              timelinePlugin,
              resourceTimelinePlugin,
            ]}` to `plugins={[
              resourceTimelinePlugin,
            ]}`

Comment: You're right, it was a CSS problem. The fullCalendar CSS has been customised by someone else and I didn't notice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled as well at the timeline chart. Finally I found that basic setup.

```js
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import resourceTimelinePlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FullCalendar
        schedulerLicenseKey="XXX"
        plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin]}
        initialView="resourceTimelineMonth"
        nowIndicator
        headerToolbar={{
          center:
            "resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineTenDay,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear",
          right: "today,prev,next,prevYear,nextYear"
        }}
        aspectRatio={3}
        resourceGroupField={"building"}
        resources={[
          { id: "a", building: "460 Bryant", title: "Auditorium A" },
          { id: "b", building: "460 Bryant", title: "Auditorium B" },
          { id: "c", building: "460 Bryant", title: "Auditorium C" },
          { id: "d", building: "420 Bryant", title: "Auditorium D" },
          { id: "e", building: "420 Bryant", title: "Auditorium E" },
          { id: "f", building: "420 Bryant", title: "Auditorium F" }
        ]}
        events={[
          {
            resourceId: "a",
            title: "event 1",
            start: "2022-12-01",
            end: "2022-12-22"
          },
          {
            resourceId: "b",
            title: "event 2",
            start: "2022-12-05T12:00:00+00:00",
            end: "2022-12-10T06:00:00+00:00"
          },

          {
            resourceId: "e",
            title: "event 3",
            start: "2022-12-09T09:00:00+00:00",
            end: "2022-12-09T14:00:00+00:00"
          }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48qXf.png)